# How to make this Perl program print in descending order?

Tags: perl, while-loop, integer

This code works but it prints in ascending order. Do I need to change my whole formula?

```
print "Enter an integer \n";
my $root = <STDIN>; 
my @nums = (100..200);    
my $i = 0;           

# code in while loop executes as long as condition is true 
while ( $i < $#nums ) 
{
    print "$nums[$i]\n",if($nums[$i] % $root == 0); $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print "Enter an integer \n";
my $root = <STDIN>; 
my @nums = (100..200);
```

> `@nums = reverse @nums; #Just reverse the arrays`

```
my $i = 0;           

# code in while loop executes as long as condition is true 
while ( $i < $#nums ) 
{
    print "$nums[$i]\n",if($nums[$i] % $root == 0); $i++;
}
```

May be it will helps you.

Comment: Oh lordddd, I've been messing with reverse this whole time and that simplified it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Just set `$i` to `$#nums` instead of `0` and decrement it `--` instead of incrementing. You'll need to change the loop condition to `$i >= 0` (it should be `$i <= $#nums` in your code, otherwise it skips `200` when `10` was entered).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

print "Enter an integer \n";
my $root = <>;
my @nums = (100 .. 200);
my $i = $#nums;

while ( $i >= 0 ) {
    print "$nums[$i]\n" if $nums[$i] % $root == 0;
    --$i;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I changed `$i > $#nums` and `$i > 99` and that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

There are more than a few ways to do it ... *not all equally good*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

run(@ARGV);

sub run {
    my $root = $_[0] // get_root();
    my @nums = (100 .. 200);

    my @functions = (
        sub {
            my ($root, $nums) = @_;
            my $i = @$nums;

            while ($i--) {
                print "$nums->[$i]\n" unless $nums->[$i] % $root;
            }
            return;
        },
        sub {
            my ($root, $nums) = @_;
            for my $n ( reverse @$nums ) {
                print "$n\n" unless $n % $root;
            }
            return;
        },
        sub {
            my ($root, $nums) = @_;
            my $i;

            while ($i++ < @$nums) {
                print "$nums->[@$nums - $i]\n" unless $nums->[@$nums - $i] % $root;
            }
            return;
        },
        sub {
            my ($root, $nums) = @_;
            my @multiples = reverse grep !($_ % $root), @$nums;
            print "$_\n" for @multiples;
            return;
        },
    );

    for my $i ( 0 ... $#functions ) {
        print "=== Function $i ===\n";
        $functions[$i]->($root, \@nums);
    }
}


sub get_root {
    return scalar <STDIN>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (my $i = $#nums; $i >= 0; --$i) { ... }

for (my $i = @nums; $i--; ) { ... }

for my $i (reverse 0 .. $#nums)  { ... }

for (1 .. @nums)  { my $i = -$_; ... }   # Or: my $i = @nums-$_;

for my $num (reverse @nums) { ... }
```

Comment: s/revere/reverse/ ?

Comment: @David Farrell, Fixed.